# Make partial page in ASP.NET Web form

Tags: asp.net, razor, webforms

I am working on ASP.NET Web form application.
I am designing page which contains alot of html elements.
I want to separate these elements and make partial pages and then include them in one page for code readability and easy maintenance.
I can do this in razor but I could not find any tutorial on this for web form.

Can anybody help?

Comment: You can use [User Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e.aspx). It is the beast way in asp.net webform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UserControl [Tutorial on UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). They are files with .ascx extension and you can include them in your pages

```
//UserControl1.ascx
<% @ Control Language="C#" ClassName="UserControl1" %>
<div>
 My Custom Control: I can use any Server controls, html tags etc
</div>
```

Include it in your .aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="MyCustomControl" Src="~/Controls/UserControl1.ascx" %>
<html>
<body>
<form runat="server">
<uc:MyCustomControl id="MyPartialView" 
    runat="server" />
 </form>
</body>
```

**For more details look here:**

[Creating a UserControl](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/user-controls/creating/)

[Using a UserControl](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/user-controls/using/)

Comment: Thanks. Worked like charm.

Comment: @ElizehStewart Glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

For `Web Form`, you can create `user control` to create a partial page.
You can read about them at this MSDN URL: [ASP.Net User Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26db8ysc(v=vs.85).aspx)

A user control is always named so it ends with `ascx` like `EditProduct.ascx` or `Registeration.ascx`. If you want to use them in a `Web Form aspx page` then you can simply drag-n-drop the user control from `Solution Explorer` in `Visual Studio IDE`. *And yes, user controls promote re-use and easier maintenance.*